# Inserting selected data using checkbox from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox, sql-server-2008-r2

When I select the in the gridview using checkbox, I want it to insert the data into the database, but it is not adding it. My code is below, please see where I am going wrong.

```
public partial class HomeTeamCheckList : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LiveGameReporting Window
        SubmitLineUp.Attributes.Add("onclick", "PassValues();");

        SubmitLineUp.Text = "Submit " + Session["HomeTeam"] + "'s Line Up";
    }

    protected void SubmitLineUp_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String GameID = string.Empty;
        String Name = string.Empty;
        String Number = string.Empty;

        int GKGVCount = GoalKeeperGridView.Rows.Count;


        foreach (GridViewRow gkrow in GoalKeeperGridView.Rows)
        {
            GameID = (String)Session["GameID"];
            Number = gkrow.Cells[0].Text;
            Name = gkrow.Cells[1].Text;

             SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(("Data Source=ROBEL-HP;Initial Catalog=RocoSportsDB;Integrated Security=True"));

            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = connection;
                cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO HTLineUp (GameID, HomeTeamLineUpNo, HomeTeamLineUpName) VALUES (@GameID,@Number,@Name)";

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameID", GameID);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", Number);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to set a breakpoint and see what exactly is getting executed.  It is most likely not what you intend.

Comment: @jadarnel27 ye it was the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); causing the problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two thoughts:

- Use a try-catch to see if you're getting any SQL errors.
- Check the return value of the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` to see if any rows were actually affected / inserted.

Like this:

```
 SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(("Data Source=ROBEL-HP;Initial Catalog=RocoSportsDB;Integrated Security=True")); 
 try
 { 
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(); 
    cmd.Connection = connection; 
    cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO HTLineUp (GameID, HomeTeamLineUpNo, HomeTeamLineUpName) VALUES (@GameID,@Number,@Name)"; 

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameID", GameID); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Number", Number); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Name); 

    // use a debugger to see if any rows were actually affected / inserted
    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
 } 
 catch(SQLException error)
 {
     // Use a debugger to see if you are getting an error on execution
     string errorText = error.message;
 }
```

Your query string looks ok, so it could be a permissions error.  But the steps above will help you track it down.